# Command line todo list manager

Tags: c, console, to-do-list, markdown

This is a tiny project of mine, a minimal command line todo list program that I regularly use to manage my todos.

It saves todos using GitHub markdown task lists format in a plain text file.

The whole thing is divided into three files: `utils.c`, `todoargs.c` and `todo.c`.

- `utils.c` contains few small utility functions along with the 2 "main" data structures used in the program, namely `StringBuffer` and `StringList`.
- `todoargs.c` deals with command line arguments which are parsed using `getopt()`. In its header are defined the 13 "operations" that can be performed on the list and a datatype, `TodoArgs`, which will hold the parsed operation and other parsed data.
- in `todo.c` each operation defined in `todoargs.h` is "translated" into a function, it also contains the `main()` function and small functions to deal with a single todo.

I'm interested in hearing everything other people have to say about my code especially about implementation, readability and "design choices". If you spot a bug or something really "nasty", please let me know =)

The code is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarcoLucidi01/todo/tree/16b414ed7cbcd57e1b2ced08dd3cce340ef9be21) in which you will find usage examples and a Makefile.

`utils.h`

```
#ifndef UTILS_HEADER
#define UTILS_HEADER

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/* Print question (which can be a format string) followed by " [y/N] " and waits
 * for user input.
 * Return true if user typed y or yes (case doesn't matter), false otherwise.
 */
bool ask_yes_no(const char *question, ...);

/* Print "error: " + error + '\n' to stderr. error can be a format string.
 */
void print_error(const char *error, ...);

/* Check if str is a replace pattern in the form /substring/replacement/ and
 * return the index of the middle slash.
 * Return 0 if str is not a replace patter.
 */
size_t is_replace_pattern(const char *str, size_t str_len);

bool file_exists_and_is_reg(const char *filepath);

bool file_exists_and_is_dir(const char *filepath);

/* Return a long int >= 0 parsed from str using base 10 which can be casted to a
 * (large enough) unsigned type.
 * str may start with white spaces, '+' or '0'. It must end with a digit.
 * The max value the function can return is LONG_MAX - 1, if str represent a
 * value greater that that, it is considered a parse error.
 * On parse error return a number < 0.
 */
long int parse_unsigned(const char *str);

/*** StringBuffer ***/

#define STRING_BUFFER_INITIAL_CAPACITY 32

/* Simple dynamic string buffer.
 * After the first append, string will always be a null-terminated cstring.
 */
typedef struct
{
        size_t length;
        size_t capacity;
        char  *string;
} StringBuffer;

/* Initializes sb fields to 0.
 */
void string_buffer_init(StringBuffer *sb);

/* Appends c to sb->string increasing its capacity if necessary.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
bool string_buffer_append_char(StringBuffer *sb, char c);

/* Appends str to sb->string increasing its capacity if necessary.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
bool string_buffer_append_string(StringBuffer *sb, const char *str);

/* Appends sb_to_app.string to sb->string increasing sb capacity if necessary.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
bool string_buffer_append_string_buffer(StringBuffer *sb, StringBuffer *sb_to_app);

/* Appends n strings from strings to sb->string.
 * If join_c is not '\0' appends join_c before each string.
 * Return true on success, false if an alloc error occurred and less than n
 * strings were appended.
 */
bool string_buffer_append_strings(StringBuffer *sb, char **strings, size_t n, char join_c);

/* Finds first occurrence of needle inside sb->string starting from index start,
 * replaces it with str and return true.
 * Return false *only if* more space was needed, but the allocation failed.
 * If needle length is 0 or an occurrence of needle doesn't exist inside
 * sb->string (after index start) doesn't perform any operation and return true.
 */
bool string_buffer_replace_from(StringBuffer *sb, size_t start,
                                const char *needle, const char *str);

/* Set sb->length to new_len if sb->capacity greater than new_len.
 */
void string_buffer_set_length(StringBuffer *sb, size_t new_len);

/* Clear content of sb->string making it an empty string.
 */
void string_buffer_clear(StringBuffer *sb);

/* Frees sb->string and calls string_buffer_init() on sb. It's safe to pass
 * NULL.
 */
void string_buffer_free(StringBuffer *sb);

/*** StringList ***/

#define STRING_LIST_INITIAL_CAPACITY 16

/* Simple dynamic list of (allocated) cstrings.
 */
typedef struct
{
        size_t length;
        size_t capacity;
        char   **list;
} StringList;

/* Return a new empty StringList of capacity STRING_LIST_INITIAL_CAPACITY.
 * Return NULL on alloc error.
 */
StringList *string_list_new(void);

/* Append str to sl increasing sl capacity if necessary.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
bool string_list_append(StringList *sl, char *str);

/* Like string_list_append() but appends an heap allocated copy of str.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
bool string_list_append_dup(StringList *sl, const char *str);

/* Return string at index i.
 */
char *string_list_get(StringList *sl, size_t i);

/* Replace string at index i with str and return the old string.
 */
char *string_list_get_replace(StringList *sl, size_t i, char *str);

/* Calls func() once for each string in sl.
 */
void string_list_for_each(StringList *sl, void (*func)(char *str));

/* Like string_list_for_each() but also passes the index of the string to
 * func().
 */
void string_list_for_each_index(StringList *sl, void (*func)(char *str, size_t i));

/* Like string_list_for_each_index() but calls func() only if test() returns
 * true.
 */
void string_list_for_each_index_if(StringList *sl,
                                   bool (*test)(const char *str),
                                   void (*func)(char *str, size_t i));

/* Calls test() once for each string in sl: if test() returns true, frees and
 * removes that string from the list.
 */
void string_list_for_each_remove_if(StringList *sl, bool (*test)(const char *str));

/* For each index in indices, frees and removes the string at that index.
 * indices array will be sorted. Indices contained in indices are assumed to be
 * unique and less then sl->length.
 * n is the number of elements in indices.
 */
void string_list_remove_multiple(StringList *sl, size_t *indices, size_t n);

/* Writes strings contained in sl to file fp.
 */
void string_list_write(StringList *sl, FILE *fp);

/* Frees and removes all strings contained in sl.
 */
void string_list_clear(StringList *sl);

/* Frees all strings contained in sl and frees memory occupied by sl too. It's
 * safe to pass NULL.
 */
void string_list_free(StringList *sl);

#endif
```

`utils.c`

```
#include "utils.h"

bool ask_yes_no(const char *question, ...)
{
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, question);
        vprintf(question, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        fputs(" [y/N] ", stdout);

        char ans[5] = { '\0' };
        int i = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < 4) {
                ans[i++] = c;
        }
        return strcasecmp(ans, "y") == 0 || strcasecmp(ans, "yes") == 0;
}

void print_error(const char *error, ...)
{
        fputs("error: ", stderr);
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, error);
        vfprintf(stderr, error, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        fputs("\n", stderr);
}

size_t is_replace_pattern(const char *str, size_t str_len)
{
        if (str_len < 3) {
                return 0;
        }
        if (str[0] != '/' || str[str_len - 1] != '/') {
                return 0;
        }
        char *middle_slash_p = strchr(str + 1, '/');
        size_t middle_slash_i = middle_slash_p - str;
        if (middle_slash_i == str_len -1) {
                return 0;
        }
        return middle_slash_i;
}

bool file_exists_and_is_reg(const char *filepath)
{
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(filepath, &st) == -1) {
                return false;
        }
        return S_ISREG(st.st_mode);
}

bool file_exists_and_is_dir(const char *filepath)
{
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(filepath, &st) == -1) {
                return false;
        }
        return S_ISDIR(st.st_mode);
}

long int parse_unsigned(const char *str)
{
        char *end_p = NULL;
        long int i = strtol(str, &end_p, 10);
        if (i < 0 || i == LONG_MAX || *end_p != '\0' || end_p == str) {
                return -1;
        }
        return i;
}

/*** StringBuffer ***/

static bool string_buffer_resize(StringBuffer *sb, size_t new_cap)
{
        void *new_str = realloc(sb->string, new_cap);
        if (new_str == NULL && new_cap > 0) {
                return false;
        }
        sb->string = new_str;
        sb->capacity = new_cap;
        return true;
}

static bool string_buffer_ensure_space(StringBuffer *sb, size_t n)
{
        if (sb->capacity - sb->length >= n) {
                return true;
        }
        size_t inc = sb->capacity > 0 ? sb->capacity / 2 : STRING_BUFFER_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        return string_buffer_resize(sb, sb->capacity + (inc > n ? inc : n));
}

static bool string_buffer_append(StringBuffer *sb, const char *buf, size_t n)
{
        if ( ! string_buffer_ensure_space(sb, n + 1)) {
                return false;
        }
        memcpy(sb->string + sb->length, buf, n);
        string_buffer_set_length(sb, sb->length + n);
        return true;
}

void string_buffer_init(StringBuffer *sb)
{
        sb->length = 0;
        sb->capacity = 0;
        sb->string = NULL;
}

bool string_buffer_append_char(StringBuffer *sb, char c)
{
        return string_buffer_append(sb, &c, 1);
}

bool string_buffer_append_string(StringBuffer *sb, const char *str)
{
        return string_buffer_append(sb, str, strlen(str));
}

bool string_buffer_append_string_buffer(StringBuffer *sb, StringBuffer *sb_to_app)
{
        return string_buffer_append(sb, sb_to_app->string, sb_to_app->length);
}

bool string_buffer_append_strings(StringBuffer *sb, char **strings, size_t n, char join_c)
{
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (join_c != '\0' && i > 0 && ! string_buffer_append_char(sb, join_c)) {
                        break;
                }
                if ( ! string_buffer_append_string(sb, strings[i])) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        return i == n;
}

bool string_buffer_replace_from(StringBuffer *sb, size_t start,
                                const char *needle, const char *str)
{
        if (sb->length == 0) {
                return true;
        }
        size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
        if (needle_len == 0) {
                return true;
        }
        char *needle_p = strstr(sb->string + start, needle);
        if (needle_p == NULL) {
                return true;
        }

        size_t needle_index = needle_p - sb->string;
        size_t str_len = strlen(str);

        if (needle_len < str_len) {
                if ( ! string_buffer_ensure_space(sb, str_len - needle_len + 1)) {
                        return false;
                }
                // sb->string pointer could change after resize
                needle_p = sb->string + needle_index;
        }

        if (needle_len < str_len || needle_len > str_len) {
                memmove(needle_p + str_len, needle_p + needle_len,
                        (sb->length + 1) - (needle_index + needle_len));
        }
        memcpy(needle_p, str, str_len);
        sb->length = sb->length - needle_len + str_len;
        return true;
}

void string_buffer_set_length(StringBuffer *sb, size_t new_len)
{
        if (sb->capacity > new_len) {
                sb->length = new_len;
                sb->string[sb->length] = '\0';
        }
}

void string_buffer_clear(StringBuffer *sb)
{
        string_buffer_set_length(sb, 0);
}

void string_buffer_free(StringBuffer *sb)
{
        if (sb != NULL) {
                free(sb->string);
                string_buffer_init(sb);
        }
}

/*** StringList ***/

static bool string_list_resize(StringList *sl, size_t new_cap)
{
        void *new_list = realloc(sl->list, sizeof(*(sl->list)) * new_cap);
        if (new_list == NULL && new_cap > 0) {
                return false;
        }
        sl->list = new_list;
        sl->capacity = new_cap;
        return true;
}

static bool string_list_grow_if_necessary(StringList *sl)
{
        if (sl->capacity - sl->length > 0) {
                return true;
        }
        return string_list_resize(sl, sl->capacity + sl->capacity / 2);
}

StringList *string_list_new(void)
{
        StringList *new_sl = malloc(sizeof(*new_sl));
        if (new_sl == NULL) {
                return NULL;
        }
        new_sl->length = 0;
        new_sl->list = NULL;
        if ( ! string_list_resize(new_sl, STRING_LIST_INITIAL_CAPACITY)) {
                free(new_sl);
                return NULL;
        }
        return new_sl;
}

bool string_list_append(StringList *sl, char *str)
{
        if ( ! string_list_grow_if_necessary(sl)) {
                return false;
        }
        sl->list[sl->length++] = str;
        return true;
}

bool string_list_append_dup(StringList *sl, const char *str)
{
        char *str_dup = strdup(str);
        if (str_dup != NULL && string_list_append(sl, str_dup)) {
                return true;
        }
        free(str_dup);
        return false;
}

char *string_list_get(StringList *sl, size_t i)
{
        return sl->list[i];
}

char *string_list_get_replace(StringList *sl, size_t i, char *str)
{
        char *old = sl->list[i];
        sl->list[i] = str;
        return old;
}

void string_list_for_each(StringList *sl, void (*func)(char *str))
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                func(sl->list[i]);
        }
}

void string_list_for_each_index(StringList *sl, void (*func)(char *str, size_t i))
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                func(sl->list[i], i);
        }
}

void string_list_for_each_index_if(StringList *sl,
                                   bool (*test)(const char *str),
                                   void (*func)(char *str, size_t i))
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                if (test(sl->list[i])) {
                        func(sl->list[i], i);
                }
        }
}

void string_list_for_each_remove_if(StringList *sl, bool (*test)(const char *str))
{
        size_t i, j;
        for (i = j = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                if (test(sl->list[i])) {
                        free(sl->list[i]);
                } else {
                        sl->list[j++] = sl->list[i];
                }
        }
        sl->length = j;
}

static int indices_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        size_t aa = *(size_t *)a;
        size_t bb = *(size_t *)b;
        if (aa > bb) {
                return 1;
        } else if (aa < bb) {
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
}

void string_list_remove_multiple(StringList *sl, size_t *indices, size_t n)
{
        qsort(indices, n, sizeof(*indices), indices_cmp);

        size_t i, j, q;
        for (i = j = q = 0; q < n; i++) {
                if (i == indices[q]) {
                        free(sl->list[i]);
                        q++;
                } else {
                        sl->list[j++] = sl->list[i];
                }
        }
        for (; i < sl->length; i++) {
                sl->list[j++] = sl->list[i];
        }
        sl->length = j;
}

void string_list_write(StringList *sl, FILE *fp)
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                fputs(sl->list[i], fp);
        }
}

void string_list_clear(StringList *sl)
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sl->length; i++) {
                free(sl->list[i]);
        }
        sl->length = 0;
}

void string_list_free(StringList *sl)
{
        if (sl != NULL) {
                string_list_clear(sl);
                free(sl->list);
                free(sl);
        }
}
```

`todoargs.h`

```
#ifndef TODOARGS_HEADER
#define TODOARGS_HEADER

#include "utils.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#define TODO_LIST_FILENAME "TODO.md"

#define TODO_FLAG_PRINT       0b00000001
#define TODO_FLAG_ADD         0b00000010
#define TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED   0b00000100
#define TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED 0b00001000
#define TODO_FLAG_EDIT        0b00010000
#define TODO_FLAG_REMOVE      0b00100000
#define TODO_FLAG_ALL         0b01000000

#define TODO_LIST_ADD                  (TODO_FLAG_ADD)
#define TODO_LIST_EDIT                 (TODO_FLAG_EDIT)
#define TODO_LIST_PRINT                (TODO_FLAG_PRINT)
#define TODO_LIST_PRINT_COMPLETED      (TODO_FLAG_PRINT | TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_PRINT_UNCOMPLETED    (TODO_FLAG_PRINT | TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_MARK_COMPLETED       (TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_MARK_UNCOMPLETED     (TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_COMPLETED   (TODO_FLAG_ALL | TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_UNCOMPLETED (TODO_FLAG_ALL | TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_REMOVE               (TODO_FLAG_REMOVE)
#define TODO_LIST_REMOVE_ALL           (TODO_FLAG_REMOVE | TODO_FLAG_ALL)
#define TODO_LIST_REMOVE_COMPLETED     (TODO_FLAG_REMOVE | TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED)
#define TODO_LIST_REMOVE_UNCOMPLETED   (TODO_FLAG_REMOVE | TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED)

typedef struct
{
        uint8_t operation;           // one of TODO_LIST_* macros.
        size_t  *indices;            // unique parsed indices.
        size_t  n_indices;
        char    *filepath;           // selected todo list filepath.
        char    **remaining_argv;
        size_t  remaining_argc;
} TodoArgs;

/* Initializes todo_args fields to 0.
 */
void todo_args_init(TodoArgs *todo_args);

/* Fills todo_args fields with arguments parsed from argv.
 * indices will not be parsed. todo_args->n_indices will be set to the expected
 * number of indices e.g in case of operation TODO_LIST_MARK_COMPLETED it will
 * be equal to todo_args->remaining_argc.
 * On parse (or alloc) error, print an error message using print_error() and
 * returns false.
 * Shows an usage message and returns false if option -h is detected.
 */
bool todo_args_parse_options(TodoArgs *todo_args, int argc, char **argv);

/* Parse at most todo_args->n_indices from todo_args->remaining_argv and stores
 * them inside todo_args->indices (which will be allocated by this function) and
 * return true.
 * On parse (or alloc) error, print an error message using print_error() and
 * returns false.
 * In particular, fails if an index is < 0 or >= upper_bound.
 * Duplicates indices are ignored, todo_args->n_indices will hold the number of
 * unique indices parsed.
 */
bool todo_args_parse_indices(TodoArgs *todo_args, size_t upper_bound);

/* Frees todo_args->filepath and todo_args->indices and calls todo_args_init()
 * on todo_args. It's safe to pass NULL.
 */
void todo_args_free(TodoArgs *todo_args);

#endif
```

`todoargs.c`

```
#include "todoargs.h"

/* Return an allocated string containing the todo list filepath.
 *
 * If filepath is not NULL and refers to a directory, return
 * "filepath/TODO_LIST_FILENAME", if it doesn't refer to a directory, return
 * "filepath".
 * If filepath is NULL and a regular file named TODO_LIST_FILENAME exist in the
 * current directory, return "TODO_LIST_FILENAME".
 * Otherwise return "$HOME/TODO_LIST_FILENAME".
 *
 * Return NULL on alloc error or if getenv("HOME") returned NULL.
 */
static char *get_todo_list_filepath(char *filepath);

static void usage(const char *exec_name)
{
        printf("Usage: %s [-f filepath] [-c] [-u] [-e] [-r] [-A] [indices]... [description]...\n"
               "\n"
               "Command line todo list.\n"
               "Saves todos using GitHub markdown task lists format in a plain text file.\n"
               "By default looks for a file named \"%s\" in the current directory, if it doesn't\n"
               "exists falls back to the main \"$HOME/%s\" file.\n"
               "If called with no arguments (besides -f), print to stdout all todos.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -f filepath     use filepath as todo list file. If filepath is a directory,\n"
               "                  looks for a file named \"%s\" inside that directory.\n"
               "\n"
               "  description...  add a new uncompleted todo to the list joining description strings.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -c              print completed todos.\n"
               "  -c indices...   mark specified todos as completed.\n"
               "  -c -A           mark all todos as completed.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -u              print uncompleted todos.\n"
               "  -u indices...   mark specified todos as uncompleted.\n"
               "  -u -A           mark all todos as uncompleted.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -e index description...  replace todo description at index index with description.\n"
               "  -e index /sub/rep/       replace first occurrence of substring sub inside todo\n"
               "                           description at index index with rep.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -r indices...   remove specified todos.\n"
               "  -r -c           remove completed todos.\n"
               "  -r -u           remove uncompleted todos.\n"
               "  -r -A           remove all todos.\n"
               "\n"
               "  -h              show this message.\n"
               "\n"
               "repository: https://github.com/MarcoLucidi01/todo\n",
               exec_name, TODO_LIST_FILENAME, TODO_LIST_FILENAME, TODO_LIST_FILENAME);
}

void todo_args_init(TodoArgs *todo_args)
{
        todo_args->operation = 0;
        todo_args->indices = NULL;
        todo_args->n_indices = 0;
        todo_args->remaining_argv = NULL;
        todo_args->remaining_argc = 0;
        todo_args->filepath = NULL;
}

bool todo_args_parse_options(TodoArgs *todo_args, int argc, char **argv)
{
        char *filepath = NULL;
        int opt;
        while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:cuerAh")) != -1) {
                switch (opt) {
                case 'f':
                        filepath = optarg;
                        break;
                case 'c':
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED;
                        break;
                case 'u':
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED;
                        break;
                case 'e':
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_EDIT;
                        break;
                case 'r':
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_REMOVE;
                        break;
                case 'A':
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_ALL;
                        break;
                case 'h':
                        usage(argv[0]);
                        return false;
                case ':':
                        print_error("option -%c requires an argument", optopt);
                        return false;
                case '?':
                        print_error("invalid option -%c", optopt);
                        return false;
                default:
                        print_error("unknown error");
                        return false;
                }
        }

        todo_args->remaining_argv = argv + optind;
        todo_args->remaining_argc = argc - optind;

        if (todo_args->operation == 0) {
                if (todo_args->remaining_argc == 0) {
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_PRINT;
                } else {
                        todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_ADD;
                }
        }

        if (todo_args->remaining_argc == 0 &&
            (todo_args->operation == TODO_FLAG_COMPLETED ||
             todo_args->operation == TODO_FLAG_UNCOMPLETED)) {
                todo_args->operation |= TODO_FLAG_PRINT;
        }

        switch (todo_args->operation) {
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT:
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT_COMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT_UNCOMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_COMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_UNCOMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_ALL:
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_COMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_UNCOMPLETED:
                if (todo_args->remaining_argc > 0) {
                        print_error("too many arguments provided");
                        return false;
                }
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_COMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_UNCOMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE:
                if (todo_args->remaining_argc < 1) {
                        print_error("missing todo index");
                        return false;
                }
                todo_args->n_indices = todo_args->remaining_argc;
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_EDIT:
                if (todo_args->remaining_argc < 2) {
                        print_error("missing todo index and/or new description");
                        return false;
                }
                todo_args->n_indices = 1;
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_ADD:
                break;
        default:
                print_error("invalid arguments");
                return false;
        }

        todo_args->filepath = get_todo_list_filepath(filepath);
        if (todo_args->filepath == NULL) {
                print_error("unable to select a valid todo list file path");
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}

static char *get_todo_list_filepath(char *filepath)
{
        StringBuffer filepath_buf;
        string_buffer_init(&filepath_buf);

        if (filepath != NULL) {
                if ( ! string_buffer_append_string(&filepath_buf, filepath)) {
                        goto error;
                }
                if (file_exists_and_is_dir(filepath_buf.string)) {
                        char *path_tail[2] = { "/", TODO_LIST_FILENAME };
                        if ( ! string_buffer_append_strings(&filepath_buf, path_tail, 2, '\0')) {
                                goto error;
                        }
                }
                return filepath_buf.string;
        }

        if ( ! string_buffer_append_string(&filepath_buf, TODO_LIST_FILENAME)) {
                goto error;
        }
        if (file_exists_and_is_reg(filepath_buf.string)) {
                return filepath_buf.string;
        }

        string_buffer_clear(&filepath_buf);
        char *home = getenv("HOME");
        if (home == NULL) {
                goto error;
        }
        char *homepath[3] = { home, "/", TODO_LIST_FILENAME };
        if ( ! string_buffer_append_strings(&filepath_buf, homepath, 3, '\0')) {
                goto error;
        }
        return filepath_buf.string;

error:
        string_buffer_free(&filepath_buf);
        return NULL;
}

bool todo_args_parse_indices(TodoArgs *todo_args, size_t upper_bound)
{
        todo_args->indices = malloc(sizeof(*(todo_args->indices)) * todo_args->n_indices);
        if (todo_args->indices == NULL) {
                return false;
        }

        bool already_seen[upper_bound];
        memset(already_seen, false, upper_bound);

        // n is the expected number of indices
        size_t n = todo_args->n_indices;

        // todo_args->n_indices will hold the number of unique indices parsed
        todo_args->n_indices = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                long int index = parse_unsigned(todo_args->remaining_argv[i]);
                if (index < 0 || (size_t)index >= upper_bound) {
                        if (index < 0) {
                                print_error("invalid index \"%s\"", todo_args->remaining_argv[i]);
                        } else {
                                print_error("index %ld is out of range", index);
                        }
                        free(todo_args->indices);
                        todo_args->indices = NULL;
                        return false;
                }
                if ( ! already_seen[index]) {
                        already_seen[index] = true;
                        todo_args->indices[todo_args->n_indices++] = index;
                }
        }

        todo_args->remaining_argv += n;
        todo_args->remaining_argc -= n;
        return true;
}

void todo_args_free(TodoArgs *todo_args)
{
        if (todo_args != NULL) {
                free(todo_args->indices);
                free(todo_args->filepath);
                todo_args_init(todo_args);
        }
}
```

`todo.c`

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "todoargs.h"
#include <errno.h>

#define TODO_HEAD_UNCOMPLETED "- [ ] "
#define TODO_HEAD_COMPLETED   "- [x] "
#define TODO_HEAD_LENGTH      6

/*** todo ***/

static bool todo_is_valid(const char *todo);
static bool todo_is_completed(const char *todo);
static bool todo_is_uncompleted(const char *todo);

static void todo_print(char *todo, size_t index);

static void todo_mark_completed(char *todo);
static void todo_mark_uncompleted(char *todo);

/* Allocates a new uncompleted todo built joining n strings from strings.
 * Return NULL on alloc error.
 */
static char *todo_build_from_strings(char **strings, size_t n);

static bool todo_is_valid(const char *todo)
{
        return todo_is_completed(todo) || todo_is_uncompleted(todo);
}

static bool todo_is_completed(const char *todo)
{
        return strncmp(todo, TODO_HEAD_COMPLETED, TODO_HEAD_LENGTH) == 0;
}

static bool todo_is_uncompleted(const char *todo)
{
        return strncmp(todo, TODO_HEAD_UNCOMPLETED, TODO_HEAD_LENGTH) == 0;
}

static void todo_print(char *todo, size_t index)
{
        printf("%2zu%s", index, todo + 1);      // skip leading -
}

static void todo_mark_completed(char *todo)
{
        todo[3] = 'x';
}

static void todo_mark_uncompleted(char *todo)
{
        todo[3] = ' ';
}

static char *todo_build_from_strings(char **strings, size_t n)
{
        StringBuffer todo_buf;
        string_buffer_init(&todo_buf);

        if ( ! string_buffer_append_string(&todo_buf, TODO_HEAD_UNCOMPLETED) ||
             ! string_buffer_append_strings(&todo_buf, strings, n, ' ') ||
             ! string_buffer_append_char(&todo_buf, '\n')) {
                string_buffer_free(&todo_buf);
                return NULL;
        }
        return todo_buf.string;
}

/*** todo_list ***/

/* Read todo list from file todo_list_fp and return a StringList containg todo
 * strings.
 * Return NULL if it reads an invalid todo or on alloc error.
 * StringList list returned should be freed. File read errors are not detected.
 */
static StringList *todo_list_read_from_file(FILE *todo_list_fp);

/* Perform the operation todo_args->operation over todo_list and return true.
 * Return false if the operation performed returned false (e.g.
 * todo_list_add()) due to an alloc error.
 * Asks for user confirmation if the operation should modify more than one todo
 * but the user did not provide the indices.
 */
static bool todo_list_do_operation(StringList *todo_list, TodoArgs *todo_args);

/* Builds a new todo from strings and appends it to todo_list.
 * Return true on success, false on alloc error.
 */
static bool todo_list_add(StringList *todo_list, char **strings, size_t n);

/* Joins n strings from strings together and edit the todo at index i:
 * if the joined string represent a replace pattern in the form
 * /substring/replacement/ replace first occurrence of substring inside todo
 * description with replacement;
 * else replace description of todo with the joined string.
 * Return false on alloc error.
 */
static bool todo_list_edit(StringList *todo_list, size_t i, char **strings, size_t n);

static void todo_list_print(StringList *todo_list);
static void todo_list_print_completed(StringList *todo_list);
static void todo_list_print_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list);

static void todo_list_mark_completed(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n);
static void todo_list_mark_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n);
static void todo_list_mark_all_completed(StringList *todo_list);
static void todo_list_mark_all_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list);

static void todo_list_remove(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n);
static void todo_list_remove_all(StringList *todo_list);
static void todo_list_remove_completed(StringList *todo_list);
static void todo_list_remove_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list);

static StringList *todo_list_read_from_file(FILE *todo_list_fp)
{
        StringBuffer todo_buf;
        string_buffer_init(&todo_buf);

        StringList *todo_list = string_list_new();
        if (todo_list == NULL) {
                goto error;
        }

        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(todo_list_fp)) != EOF) {
                if ( ! string_buffer_append_char(&todo_buf, c)) {
                        goto error;
                }
                if (c == '\n') {
                        if ( ! todo_is_valid(todo_buf.string) ||
                             ! string_list_append_dup(todo_list, todo_buf.string)) {
                                goto error;
                        }
                        string_buffer_clear(&todo_buf);
                }
        }

        string_buffer_free(&todo_buf);
        return todo_list;
error:
        string_buffer_free(&todo_buf);
        string_list_free(todo_list);
        return NULL;
}

static bool todo_list_do_operation(StringList *todo_list, TodoArgs *todo_args)
{
        switch (todo_args->operation) {
        case TODO_LIST_ADD:
                return todo_list_add(todo_list, todo_args->remaining_argv, todo_args->remaining_argc);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_EDIT:
                return todo_list_edit(todo_list, todo_args->indices[0],
                                      todo_args->remaining_argv, todo_args->remaining_argc);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT:
                todo_list_print(todo_list);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT_COMPLETED:
                todo_list_print_completed(todo_list);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_PRINT_UNCOMPLETED:
                todo_list_print_uncompleted(todo_list);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_COMPLETED:
                todo_list_mark_completed(todo_list, todo_args->indices, todo_args->n_indices);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_UNCOMPLETED:
                todo_list_mark_uncompleted(todo_list, todo_args->indices, todo_args->n_indices);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_COMPLETED:
                if (ask_yes_no("are you sure you want to mark all todos as completed?")) {
                        todo_list_mark_all_completed(todo_list);
                }
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_ALL_UNCOMPLETED:
                if (ask_yes_no("are you sure you want to mark all todos as uncompleted?")) {
                        todo_list_mark_all_uncompleted(todo_list);
                }
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE:
                todo_list_remove(todo_list, todo_args->indices, todo_args->n_indices);
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_ALL:
                if (ask_yes_no("are you sure you want to remove all todos?")) {
                        todo_list_remove_all(todo_list);
                }
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_COMPLETED:
                if (ask_yes_no("are you sure you want to remove completed todos?")) {
                        todo_list_remove_completed(todo_list);
                }
                break;
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE_UNCOMPLETED:
                if (ask_yes_no("are you sure you want to remove uncompleted todos?")) {
                        todo_list_remove_uncompleted(todo_list);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
}

static bool todo_list_add(StringList *todo_list, char **strings, size_t n)
{
        char *new_todo = todo_build_from_strings(strings, n);
        if (new_todo != NULL && string_list_append(todo_list, new_todo)) {
                return true;
        }
        free(new_todo);
        return false;
}

static bool todo_list_edit(StringList *todo_list, size_t i, char **strings, size_t n)
{
        StringBuffer join_buf;
        string_buffer_init(&join_buf);
        if ( ! string_buffer_append_strings(&join_buf, strings, n, ' ')) {
                string_buffer_free(&join_buf);
                return false;
        }

        char *todo = string_list_get(todo_list, i);
        size_t todo_len = strlen(todo);
        StringBuffer todo_buf = {
                .length   = todo_len,
                .capacity = todo_len + 1,
                .string   = todo
        };

        bool ret = false;

        size_t middle_slash_i = is_replace_pattern(join_buf.string, join_buf.length);

        if (middle_slash_i > 0) {
                join_buf.string[middle_slash_i] = '\0';
                join_buf.string[join_buf.length - 1] = '\0';

                const char *sub = join_buf.string + 1;
                const char *rep = join_buf.string + middle_slash_i + 1;

                ret = string_buffer_replace_from(&todo_buf, TODO_HEAD_LENGTH, sub, rep);
        } else {
                if (string_buffer_append_char(&join_buf, '\n')) {
                        string_buffer_set_length(&todo_buf, TODO_HEAD_LENGTH);
                        ret = string_buffer_append_string_buffer(&todo_buf, &join_buf);
                }
        }

        // todo_buf.string could be a new pointer after resize. No need to free
        // the old one, StringBuffer has take care of that.
        string_list_get_replace(todo_list, i, todo_buf.string);
        string_buffer_free(&join_buf);
        return ret;
}

static void todo_list_print(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each_index(todo_list, todo_print);
}

static void todo_list_print_completed(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each_index_if(todo_list, todo_is_completed, todo_print);
}

static void todo_list_print_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each_index_if(todo_list, todo_is_uncompleted, todo_print);
}

static void todo_list_mark_completed(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n)
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                todo_mark_completed(string_list_get(todo_list, indices[i]));
        }
}

static void todo_list_mark_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n)
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                todo_mark_uncompleted(string_list_get(todo_list, indices[i]));
        }
}

static void todo_list_mark_all_completed(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each(todo_list, todo_mark_completed);
}

static void todo_list_mark_all_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each(todo_list, todo_mark_uncompleted);
}

static void todo_list_remove(StringList *todo_list, size_t *indices, size_t n)
{
        string_list_remove_multiple(todo_list, indices, n);
}

static void todo_list_remove_all(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_clear(todo_list);
}

static void todo_list_remove_completed(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each_remove_if(todo_list, todo_is_completed);
}

static void todo_list_remove_uncompleted(StringList *todo_list)
{
        string_list_for_each_remove_if(todo_list, todo_is_uncompleted);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;

        FILE *todo_list_fp = NULL;
        StringList *todo_list = NULL;

        TodoArgs todo_args;
        todo_args_init(&todo_args);

        if ( ! todo_args_parse_options(&todo_args, argc, argv)) {
                goto done;
        }

        todo_list_fp = fopen(todo_args.filepath, "r");

        if (todo_list_fp == NULL && errno == ENOENT &&
            ask_yes_no("file %s doesn't exists. Do you want to create it?", todo_args.filepath)) {
                todo_list_fp = fopen(todo_args.filepath, "w+");
        }
        if (todo_list_fp == NULL) {
                print_error("unable to open todo list file %s", todo_args.filepath);
                goto done;
        }

        todo_list = todo_list_read_from_file(todo_list_fp);
        if (todo_list == NULL) {
                print_error("unable to read todo list file %s, maybe some todo is invalid", todo_args.filepath);
                goto done;
        }

        switch (todo_args.operation) {
        case TODO_LIST_EDIT:
        case TODO_LIST_REMOVE:
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_COMPLETED:
        case TODO_LIST_MARK_UNCOMPLETED:
                // operation requires at least one todo index
                if ( ! todo_args_parse_indices(&todo_args, todo_list->length)) {
                        goto done;
                }
        }

        if ( ! todo_list_do_operation(todo_list, &todo_args)) {
                print_error("unable to perform the operation on todo list");
                goto done;
        }

        if ( ! (todo_args.operation & TODO_FLAG_PRINT)) {
                // operation was not a simple print, we need to persist the todo list
                if (freopen(todo_args.filepath, "w", todo_list_fp) == NULL) {
                        print_error("unable to save changes on todo list file %s", todo_args.filepath);
                        goto done;
                }
                string_list_write(todo_list, todo_list_fp);
        }

        exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
done:
        todo_args_free(&todo_args);
        if (todo_list_fp != NULL) {
                fclose(todo_list_fp);
        }
        string_list_free(todo_list);
        exit(exit_status);
}
```

Comment: After `string_buffer_init()`, should `.string`, always point to a null character terminated C string after returning from some `string_...()`?  If so, it is unclear why `string_buffer_set_length()` has test `if (sb->capacity > new_len)` before doing `sb->string[sb->length] = '\0';`.  It looks like a hole that could result in a non-null character array.

Comment: @chux yes, after a (successful) `string_append_*()` call, `sb->string` should point to a null-terminated string. I added that test to "avoid problems" if `string_buffer_set_length()` (or `string_buffer_clear()`) is called after a `string_buffer_init()` but before any append operation. Maybe I should limit the use of `set_length()` to `new_len` values strictly less than `sb->length`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program expects the user to refer to completed or incomplete tasks by a numeric index.  However, the Markdown file contains an unnumbered bulleted list, which forces the user to count the items manually (starting from 0).  That design is inhumane.  I suggest that you change the Markdown to use numbered lists.

By the way, "uncompleted" is not common in English usage.  I suggest rewording it as ["incomplete"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncompleted%2C+incomplete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncompleted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincomplete%3B%2Cc0).

You are missing some required `#includes`.  On my system, I see that…

- `todoargs.c` needs to `#include <unistd.h>`:

  ```
  $ make
  gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -o todo.o todo.c
  gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -o todoargs.o todoargs.c
  todoargs.c:68:23: error: implicit declaration of function 'getopt' is invalid in
        C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:cuerAh")) != -1) {
  …
  ```

  This omission is your fault.
- `utils.c` has a warning-treated-as-an-error when I compile it with clang 10.0.0 on macOS 10.13:

  ```
  $ make
  gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -o todoargs.o todoargs.c
  gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -o utils.o utils.c
  utils.c:245:25: error: implicit declaration of function 'strdup' is invalid in
        C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          char *str_dup = strdup(str);
                          ^
  …
  ```

  Actually, `utils.c` includes `utils.h`, which in turn includes `string.h` already.  I believe that this is a bug in macOS/XCode, and have filed Apple Radar 45714179 for it.  My reasoning:

  1. [According to the X/OPEN group documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), `strdup()` first appeared in Issue 4, Version 2, then moved from X/OPEN UNIX extension to BASE in Issue 5.
  2. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#1997:_Single_UNIX_Specification_version_2), SUSv2 includes "the Base Definitions, Issue 5", which should therefore include `strdup()`.
  3. [According to GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-_005fXOPEN_005fSOURCE), `#define XOPEN_SOURCE 500` will include definitions from the Single Unix Specification, version 2. Your code compiles just fine for me on Linux.  Also, [IBM's z/OS documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/ftms.htm) confirms that `#define XOPEN_SOURCE 500` makes available certain key functions that are associated with Single UNIX Specification, Version 2.
  4. The [Apple man page on `strdup(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strdup.3.html) merely says that "The `strdup()` function first appeared in 4.4BSD", and does not specify what versioning macros are necessary to obtain its declaration.  Your code does compile cleanly on macOS with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600`, but I don't believe that that is a reasonable requirement.

Comment: *"Inhumane"* - harsh, but true.  I'm a native speaker and don't find *uncompleted* uncommon - but I do agree with [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncompleted)'s note that *"The word often carries the connotation of "the result of a failure to complete", rather than just incomplete.*  IOW, "incomplete" suggests the possibility of future completion.

Comment: _inhumane_, jeez! Ok, I will add numbers to the raw file, you convinced me!
English it's not my native language, I thought _uncompleted_ meant _not completed_, thank you for pointing that out!
And for missing `unistd.h`, it was an oversight, however the code compiles just
fine on my system `gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516` without it,
that's why I didn't notice. Do you have any clues about how it is possible?

Comment: It happens all the time that code compiles even with missing includes. On of your existing includes likely happens to use unistd.h. It's not portable code, though.

Comment: Is there any compiler flag that I can add to avoid such situations?

Comment: I don't think that it's the compiler's job to verify your code. You can use a static analyzer, such as [Include-What-You-Use](https://include-what-you-use.org/) (which I haven't tried myself).